# Convert float to integer in Python - invalid literal error

Tags: python, json, floating-point

How do I convert this number to an integer I can do simple math with?!
(eg. 10.5200 below.)

```
{"bid":["10.52000000","0.70824000"],"ask":["10.54000000","2.07336000"],"seq":2456916}
```

I get the following error, and it's driving me mental:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.52'
```

This is what I'm running:

```
bitfl = json.loads(bitfl)
bid = bitfl['bid']
ask = bitfl['ask']
bidd = bid[0] #edit - this is actually in, as it's a list
askk = ask[0]
print('diff: %i' % (int(bidd[0]) - int(askk[0])))
```

I don't know WHY it should be so difficult to just accept "10.52" as a string or float or unicode and just convert it to a normal, calculable integer!

Any help MUCH appreciated!

Comment: `10.52` is obviously not a valid integer. Convert to float and then to int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to convert a *string* containing a non-integer to an integer.

The easiest/best solution is using `int(float(yourstring))`

Since you receive the data as JSON you should also consider requiring whatever client is providing the data not to use strings for non-string data.

Comment: @KnutOle: What about them?  If you want an integer you need to get rid of the decimals, since integers are whole numbers.

Comment: You still get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: -` Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write `int(float(bidd[0]))`